# Hashing user passwords when using HTTPS

Tags: sql-server, security, hash, https, passwords

Should passwords be hashed in the client side using the hash(password + salt) method even if I'm using HTTPS? or should I just hash it when it arrives to SQL SERVER 2008 R2 with a built in function? Thank You.

Comment: I'd imagine it adds another layer of protection by sending a hashed and salted password instead of in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you hash in the client side? Is this a single page app written in Javascript? Even then, you must have some server side language connecting to a database (ASP.NET? PHP?). Do your salting and hashing on the server side. Client side smells bad to me ... for some reason the salting/hashing procedure seems more prone to attack if you've got the logic and random generation happening client side. I can't point to a specific attack - but it just seems like a needless thing to push to the client (unless perhaps you can't get SSL).

It's not particularly important whether you do it in your server side language or directly in the database. I prefer doing your calculations in the code, and then sending the final hash over to SQL. Using built in SQL Server functions is annoying and there's problems between versions - and your code is forever locked away in Microsoft-land.

**TL;DR** Do it server-side, not client, and not in database directly. HTTPS is necessary if you want that plaintext password encrypted over the line before you send (definitely should).

Comment: Like what if your user decides to intercept the Javascript and instead sends the password unsalted to your database, or who knows what they could send instead.

Comment: I agree with Mike on the client side part of this - what if someone had JavaScript disabled - no encryption at all? I have stronger feelings about NOT using the database - which leads me to the same conclusion as Mike too. Do it in the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the salting of passwords is (also) useful if somebody finds a security breach and steals the list of passwords from the database. If salted, it is almost impossible to find back the clear passwords with methods like rainbow tables. Otherwise, they can be cracked.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that HTTPS is broken, a lot of security consequences arise. Basically everything falls apart.

Don't do this. It is a waste of your time. Use it in some better way, like developing a feature the user cares about.

Just do the standard hashing and salting on the server and try not to invent new security schemes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSL, the communication between client and server is encrypted.

The second half of the question is slightly trickier. While SQL Server has built-in encryption, it suffers the problem of being usable by anyone with access to the database.

If you encrypt in code and send the encrypted version to the database, it gives you protection in the event of a database compromise - they may have broken into your database but they can't decrypt the data.

So my answer is... neither client side, not database - encrypt and salt in the code in between the two!